# Existing WordPress installation and Laravel 5 app

Tags: wordpress, laravel, laravel-5

I have got an existing WordPress installation. I would like to call a Laravel 5 application from some WordPress pages. The Laravel application implements an online training that comes with its own views and functionality.

I have read a lot of tutorials on the web and here at stackoverflow that describe a complete integration of the two backends.

However, my goal is to leave the WordPress installation as it is, if that is possible, and add the Laravel functionality.

My requirements are

- the Laravel app needs to know which user is currently logged in with
  DigiMember in WordPress
- the Laravel installation directories are located outside of the WordPress installation directories to have a clear cut between the two applications
- nice to have: the Laravel views are
  integrated in a specific WordPress site, i.e. the header and footer of the site are shown by WordPress and the actual content is served by the Laravel app

Is it possible to set up WordPress and Laravel to meet my requirements without touching too much of the existing WordPress installation?

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/corcel/corcel ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are dealing with an existing legacy application... You can try to make your site point to laravel application and add rules to .htaccess file which will redirect to wordpress app if 404 is thrown (not sure how to do that, never tried myself)...

But you expect to much out of this, if you wanna use laravel templates in parts of wordpress application... You could load them dynamically with ajax after the page is loaded or something... and you could have routes in laravel which only serve certain templates and use it that way...